# 1-norm and 2-norm

Tags: inequality, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $u$ and $v$ be unit vectors over some finite dimensional complex Hilbert space. We are given that

$$\|u u^{*} - v v^{*} \|_1 \leq \epsilon$$

We want to upper bound

$$\|u  - v  \|_2$$

I have tried using Fuchs van de Graaf and other inequalities but haven't succeeded much.

Comment: Can you expand on it more?

Comment: Just making sure: $u^*$ here denotes the (vector) complex conjugate?

Comment: What if $v=-u$?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. If $u = -v$ or $u=sv$ with $|s|=1$ then $uu^*-vv^*=0$ while $\|u-v\|_2 \ne0$ for $s\ne1$.

Now assume that $u,v$ are linearly independent.
Since you are talking about Fuchs-van de Graaf, I suppose $\|T\|_1$ refers to the Schatten-1-norm of $T$, or the trace of the operator $(T^*T)^{1/2}$.

In our case $T = uu^*-vv^*$ is self-adjoint. So $\|T\|_1$ is the sum of the absolute values of the eigenvalues of $T$.

Now, the nontrivial eigenspaces of $T$ are spanned by $u$ and $v$, and
the operator $T = uu^*-vv^*$ has the same non-zero eigenvalues as the matrix
$\pmatrix{ 1 & -v^*u \\ u^*v & -1}$, which is the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $(u,v)$ of $span(u,v)$. These eigenvalues are $\pm \sqrt{1- |u^*v|^2}$. So $\|T\|_1 = 2\sqrt{1- |u^*v|^2}$.
The vector difference can be written as
$$\|u-v\|^2 = 2(1- \Re(u^*v)),$$
which seems structurally similar. But I cannot see how to bound it in terms of $\|T\|_1$ even for $T\ne0$.

Comment: Assuming linear independence won't help get an inequality as you can take $v_n$ independent of $u$ with $v_n\to -u$. The 1-norm converges to 0 and the 2-norm converges to 2.